# Wordpress Domain Mapping, which folder(s) to backup?

Tags: wordpress

It took me a while to get domain mapping working on wordpress. I set it up using debian. I was just wondering which folders I should backup in the event of a server re-install where I can just drag in the saved folders and domain mapping should be working again. Unless I have to go through the steps all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should backup all user generated files like **plugins**, **themes**, and **upload files** which are all under in the **wp-content** folder. Also, take care of the **wp-config.php** which includes the db connect setting of your site and the **.htaccess** file which contains the server config for your site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I saw this a while ago, I apologize not selecting it right away. I don't have any users, I only used wordpress for the domain mapping aspect but I would like to not repeat the rather tedious process of setting it up. Thanks.